# Is the expression 'asked for a special permission' grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

It appeared in an English test for foreign learners recently, where the candidates had to choose the right word to fill in the blank. On the subject of Covid, the question is:

- *Some parents have asked for a special [permission/admission/interest/stage] to come to school ...*

The only logical answer here, given Covid restrictions, is 'permission'. I'm wondering why the answer reads "asked for ***a*** special permission" and not "asked for special permission".

"... a special interest" sounds more natural and a lot of students chose this as their answer on grammatical grounds.

Comment: I think it's an error in the setting of the test. Errors like that happen more than you might imagine. The difficulty the setters had was that the three wrong options all require the indefinite article even though the correct one does not.

Comment: Permission is sought or asked? I usually hear people use "..request your permission, seek your permission, etc." Not sure of what the native speakers use.

Comment: Related: [“Have permission” vs “have a permission”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354911/).

Answer (score 1):

Nouns once solely used in non-count usages often become countified, that is they become  used in what become accepted count usages. Zwicky, at [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=501), includes *E-mail*, *spam* and *slang* as nouns that have recently undergone countification. So it is wise to check on whether 'permission' has undergone such a transformation, allowing the count usage (a permission, three permissions), perhaps more idiomatic with 'padding' (a special permission).

There are certainly computer-related examples, but [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/permission) goes further, having:

> **permission** (2) ​[countable, usually plural] an official written statement allowing somebody to do something
>
> - *The publisher is responsible for obtaining the necessary permissions to reproduce illustrations.*
> - *The report recommends that all planning permissions for quarrying in national parks should expire in ten years.*

It is arguable whether the example in the test really sufficiently fulfils the 'official' caveat mentioned here, and the dictionary *does* say that this usage is more commonly encountered in the plural form.

[Wiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/permission) goes no further than to say that *permission* has count and non-count usages, without examining any caveats that attach.

As I'm a septuagenarian native-speaking Oxford grad, and had to check for countness, and still can't decide on whether 'a special permission' is acceptable in this example, I'd say the test is unfair.

Comment: The authors of the test probably treated it as countable because they had in their minds a process in which some bureaucrat would write out a chit permitting the parents to come to school; the countability of the chits then made the permissions themselves countable.